# How to input a two dimmensional array from a function

Tags: c

I currently am trying to find the grid size of a sample of data from using command window redirection. Every time I execute the program, my cmd stops working.

How do I fix this?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int inputData(int [][500]); //inputs the data and returns the rows by 
columns.

int main(void){
    int n = 0;
    int data[n][n];

    printf("Grid size: %dx%d", inputData(data),inputData(data));

    return 0;
}

int inputData(int data[][500]){
    int i;
    int j;

    for(i = 1; i <= 500; i++){  
        for(j = 0; j <= 500; j++){
            scanf("%d", &data[i][j]);
        }
    }
    return j;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First, n has be set to 500 in main.

Second, in the function, the iteration of i and j should be from 0 to 499.
Remember that in C, the index starts from 0, not 1.

Comment: Which usually means is written `i = 0; i < 500; i++`. See the `<=` difference.

Answer (score 0):

n = 0, but you iterate through a 500x500 array, so you get a segmentation fault. Make n = 500